# Set environment Path Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

Trying to add stuff to the system environment Path via batch, vbs or anything really.

This used to work in a .bat, but has stopped:

```
setx -m path "C:\addtopath;%PATH%"
```

This used to work in VBS, but has also stopped:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM") 
WshEnv("Path") = WshEnv("Path") & ";C:\addtopath"
```

This keeps saying invalid syntax when I try to modify the registry:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%path%;C:\addtopath" /f
```

I am really stumped on this one. I need a solution that will always work. I am running it **as administrator**, but it still not working.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "used to work, byt also stopped"? Any errors or just fails silently?

Comment: How long is your actual `PATH` value? There have been limits on the maximum length IIRC.

Comment: Was getting: Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s). It did not exceed maxlength.

Comment: Double post: http://superuser.com/questions/625116/default-option-is-not-allowed-more-than-2-times

Comment: Shouldn't be `Session Manager`(A space between `Session` and `Manager`)

Answer (score 0):

try to add it into `PATH` using GUI, right click on My Computer select Properties, and find Environment Variables, then edit the value of `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I somehow had a " end up in the actual PATH value...

I had to type `PATH` into CMD, copy out the contents, and overwrite it with `setx PATH "contents here"`. (Of course, don't make any mistakes when you do this.)