# Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s)

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Trying to use:

```
setx -m path "C:\addtopath;%PATH%"
```

Error Invalid: Syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s). Type "SETX /?" for usage.

It is in quotes though???

Comment: Have you took a look into `setx /?`? Seems like you want `setx path "%PATH%;C:\addtopath" /M`.

Comment: Double post: http://superuser.com/questions/625111/set-environment-path-windows-7